# Группировка значений в массив по ключам javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Есть массив:

```
[{
   continent: 'Europa', 
   country: 'Russia', 
   region: 'Moskovska obl'
},
{
   continent: 'Europa', 
   country: 'Russia', 
   region: 'Tumenskaya obl'
},
{
   continent: 'North America', 
   country: 'USA', 
   region: 'Toronto'
},
{
   continent: 'North America', 
   country: 'USA', 
   region: 'Texas'
}]
```

Необходимо преобразовать в структуру:

`[
{
   continent {
      name: 'Europa',
      countries:[{
        name: 'Russia',
        regions: [{
          name: 'Moskovska obl'
        },
        {
          name: 'Tumenskaya obl'
        }]
      }]
    }
},
{
 continent {
     name: 'North America',
      countries:[{
        name: 'USA',
        regions: [{
          name: 'Toronto'
        },
        {
          name: 'Texas'
        }]
      }]
    }
}
]`

Можете подсказать как сделать преобразование?

Comment: `[continent: '', country: '', region: '']` - в данной строке синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: поправил, но я думаю суть изначальной структуры ясна

Comment: интересно, как ключ `country` превращается в `countries`

Comment: Мне данные приходят как в первом массиве, и надо преобразовать эту структуру - объединить страны в континенты, а регионы в страны

Comment: @zm1994 Вы не хотите привести нормальный пример входных и выходных данных? И поправьте, пожалуйста, формат второго объекта.

Comment: написал пример как должно выглядеть

Comment: для группировки используй [функцию reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: все конечно круто, но я не фига не поверю что человек только-что взявшийся изучать программирование начинает с формирования json и работы с api. сто пудов это какой-то офигевший чел который хочет за счет других зарабатывать. Сам сидит курит и телек смотрит, а ты значит херачь сложную нормализацию данных. МИНУС

Comment: @OlmerDale, не нужно оценивать личность вопрошающего. Он пришёл и ушёл, а вопрос остался. Оценивайте вопрос - будет ли он полезен, тем, кто придёт сюда позже.

Answer (score 3):

С помощью [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) и промежуточных словарей:

```js
{
     let data = [
          {continent: 'Europa', country: 'Russia', region: 'Moskovska obl'},
          {continent: 'Europa', country: 'Russia', region: 'Tumenskaya obl'},
          {continent: 'North America', country: 'USA', region: 'Toronto'},
          {continent: 'North America', country: 'USA', region: 'Texas'}
     ];

     let continents = {};
     let countries = {};
     let regions = {};

     let grouped = data.reduce((res, reg) => {
          if (!res.continents) res.continents = [];
          if (!continents[reg.continent]) {
               let continent = {name: reg.continent, countries: []};
               res.continents.push(continent);
               continents[reg.continent] = continent;
          }
          if (!countries[reg.country]) {
               let country = {name: reg.country, regions: []};
               continents[reg.continent].countries.push(country);
               countries[reg.country] = country;
          }
          if (!regions[reg.region]) {
               let region = {name: reg.region};
               countries[reg.country].regions.push(region);
               regions[reg.region] = region;
          }
          return res;

     }, {});

     console.log(grouped)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло

Comment: В этом коде присутствует немного очевидного и несложно выпиливаемого нарушения DRY